# What is the roughest surface?

Tags: material-science

If smoothness is defined by the friction between two surfaces, which surfaces have maximum friction?

For instance, sandpaper is considered fairly rough, but it's not the roughest surface in existence. What material could be considered the roughest surface?

Comment: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Tribology

Comment: Pretty sure smoothness *is not* defined by friction between two surfaces. Because then when machining parts, two different materials would be considered to have different smoothness when they have the same finish which is not the case. When measuring a part for smoothness, they do not measure friction.

Answer (score 2):

Two clean surfaces brought together in a clean environment can have a interface strength of up to that of the bulk material (in excess of 1 GPa in certain alloys). And one can always design an extremely corrugated and "sticky" surface that's amenable to both interlocking and adhesion. In this sense, there's really no upper limit to roughness/friction except an arbitrary threshold of when one passes from friction to mechanical immobilization.

Comment: What do you mean by interface strength?

Comment: I mean the cohesion or energy cost of breaking the material apart.